# Create multidimensional arrays using single table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a table like this;

```
**Year**   **Month**
2012        Jan
2012        Mar
2012        Apr
2013        Dec
2013        Nov
```

And I am trying to create an array from this table similar to below;

```
Array
(
    [2012] => Array(
              Jan, Mar, Apr),
    [2013] => Array(
              Dec, Nov)
);
```

so far I tried this code, but didn't get what I want,

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

          $new_array[] = array(
            'year' => $row['year'],
            'month' => $row['month'],
          );
}
```

Comment: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: @krishna, you are right, mysql_* are very outdated and unsecure. In fact, they are deprecated. These functions are good for learning, but once you understand the basics, you should pick something more secure, like PDO or ORM from some framework. In worst case, you still can use mysqli_* functions, but I still don't recommend to do that.

Comment: @Megakuh I think you thought it as a question.It a link to learn why you should not use mysql_* function.

Comment: @krishna, yeah, I noticed that later on and correct myself a little bit :-)

Comment: @Megakuh mysqli is all right. Prepared statements are key.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          $new_array[$row['year']][] = $row['month'];
}
```

Comment: +1 I thinks its very simplest solution that can be ever achieved for this question

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but this is uncorrect solution. If problem of getting data can be solved on DATAbase layer, they it should be solved like that.

Comment: @Megakuh it is not problem of getting data, its problem of storing the retrived data.

Comment: @Megakuh How can you say incorrect solution can you explain?

Comment: @Sadikhasan, I did already. From terms of syntax, etc. - your proposal is correct. From terms of software design - using GROUP_CONCAT function in DB query is much more preferable. If I did code review for such task, I would allow both solutions, but if I would have to pick better one, DB layer usage is much more right here.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be using MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` and `GROUP` to create a result of a row per year, then use PHP's `explode` to split the `GROUP_CONCAT`enated value to an array:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `year`, GROUP_CONCAT(`month`) AS `months` FROM table GROUP BY `year`");
$new_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $new_array[$row['year']] = explode(',', $row['months']);
}
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is depricated. You should not advice OP to use it

Comment: @RahilWazir i am not forcing OP to use it. It is specifying a good advice to him.And here i am mentioning to the one who answers this.Generally when you answer using deprecated function(without saying it is deprecated) it is a bad solution

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_array=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

      if(!isset($new_array[$row['year']])
        $new_array[$row['year']]=array();

       $new_array[$row['year']] = array_push($new_array[$row['year']],$row['month']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `while` loop to this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $new_array[$row['year']][] = $row['month'];
}
```

Comment: I really don't mind downvotes, but an explanation would be helpful.

Comment: I downvoted when you first posted and it was wrong(you missed the `[]` before the equals sign), now it's too late for me to remove unless you edit again.

Comment: Yes, I saw that the minute I hit enter, and changed it right away. I guess you were quicker than my edit :). Made a small edit, hope you can undo it now.

Comment: My vote is undone, but there's still someone else having downvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below line
create the array in outside the loop.

```
 $newArray=array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($(result))
    $newArray[$row['year']] = $row['month'];
```

Comment: check my answer by print the array.                                  foreach($newArray as $year => $month){
    echo $year."=>".$month;
}

Comment: see it will result like `2012=> jan` , `2012=> feb` , `2013=> Dec`. but op asked to create an array for all months of 2012 and 2013 seperately